# BootstrapError, Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


# Create your views here.
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
        
    context = {form: 'form'}
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)
```

form.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

signup.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}

  <form method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="signup" class="boxed-btn3 w-100">
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

why get error:  raise BootstrapError('Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.' , although it works on the login.html page

login.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}

  {% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
      please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="login" class="boxed-btn3 w-100">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
  </form>

  {# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
  <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

I tried use {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %} but not worked.
How can I solve this error
I use bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `context` dict, you confused between key and values so:

```
context = {'form': form}
```